# Can I customize the icon for a link in my Bookmarks Bar on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is it possible to change the icon in my Bookmarks Bar ?

[image]

Or, if they cannot be changed, could I remove the icons all together and just leave a text link ?

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome bookmarks bar is excellent and it is great to be able to sync with other computers. I recently discovered I could add folders to the bookmarks bar instead of individual bookmarks. This made organizing bookmarks easier and provided enhanced access to them. The only downside is that folders all look the same, so a previously colorful bar is now filled with identical folders. Not only this doesn't look so nice, but the bookmark icons (generated by the respective sites) help distinguish between them and access them faster. If we could assign icons/images to each folder, it would be perfect. Congrats on a fine browser!

Google Chrome version: 4.0.249.89 (Official Build 38071) 
Operating System: Windows XP SP3